# Class 'Darksky\Darksky' not found in Laravel using the Darksky Weather API?

Tags: php, laravel

Using the Laravel Darksky API

I added the service provider to the providers array in config/app.php

`Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\LaravelDarkSkyServiceProvider::class`

and registered a facade accessor to config/app.php aliases array

`'DarkSky' => \Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\Facades\DarkSky::class`

So I called

```
use Darksky\Darksky;

Route::get('/', function () {
    DarkSky::location(90, 71)->get();
    return view('welcome');
});
```

But I get this error,

> Class 'Darksky\Darksky' not found

What is wrong?

Comment: Note that the namespace of this package is `Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky` so you should do `use Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\Darksky;` instead of `use Darksky\Darksky;` See https://github.com/naughtonium/laravel-dark-sky/blob/master/src/DarkSky.php#L9

Comment: the example calls method location statically now I get this error Non-static method Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\DarkSky::location() should not be called statically.

Comment: My bad, try using the Facade: Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\Facades\DarkSky

Comment: new error ReflectionException (-1)
Class darksky does not exist

Comment: Namespaces and class names are case sensitive. Make sure you are respecting it.

Comment: every part of my code is DarkSky not darksky.

Comment: Let's start over. What happens if you comment the DarkSky call in your route and do `{{ dd(DarkSky::location(90, 71)->get()) }}` from your blade view?

Comment: same error ReflectionException (-1) Class darksky does not exist

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: same error reflectionException (-1) Class darksky does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a facade to the `aliases` array, in this case:

```
'DarkSky' => \Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\Facades\DarkSky::class
```

that will make a facade available to use in the root namespace. You're trying to access it as if it was available in the `DarkSky` namespace.

```
use DarkSky\DarkSky;
```

You should change this line to:

```
use DarkSky;
```

or alternatively, you can use the facade directly instead of its root alias by changing it to:

```
use Naughtonium\LaravelDarkSky\Facades\DarkSky;
```